# Python3 issue regarding index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

I am having this problem. When i run this code, with the above file it gives me a index out of range error.

```
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
file_contents = [x.split('\t')[2:5] for x in f.readlines()]
#Set the variables for average and total for cities

total = 0
city = set()
for line in file_contents:
     print(line[0])
```

This is the content for the file

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Music   66.08   Cash
2012-01-01  09:00   Pittsburgh  Pet Supplies    493.51  Discover
2012-01-01  09:00   Omaha   Children's Clothing 235.63  MasterCard
```

Comment: Did you try `print(line)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file after reading from it, the recommended practice is to open it using the `with` statement which automatically closes it;

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    file_contents = [x.split(' ')[2:5] for x in f.readlines()]
    #Set the variables for average and total for cities

total = 0
city = set()
for line in file_contents:
     print(line[0])
```

However the issue you are having is splitting the lines by `\t`, use a blank space and it should give you what you need.

> OUTPUT

```
09:00
09:00
09:00
09:00
09:00
```

Comment: the code above did not solve the issue. It still has the same error as `list index out of range`

Comment: Your issue is with the slicing `[2:5]` and how you are splitting the data. For example, if you remove the `[2:5]` you will see that the whole file prints without any problems. Or, like I have, if you split the data by a physical space, you can keep the slicing because the data is being split correctly.

Comment: i split it into `[2:5]` is because i want to print the item category, price and mode of payment.

Comment: Regardless of your intent, it's still the reason why this is failing. You either need to change how you split each line in the file or change the file itself to use different delimiters. The above code works without issue for me, whereas your code gives me the `list index out of range` error